# How to pass a repository object to the next route in flutter using go_router in web?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-go-router

I have a repository object which I want to use for two blocs (list view bloc and edit dialog bloc). I.e.

```dart
class Repo {
  addEntity();
  getEntity();
  fetchEntities();
  ...
}

class ListViewBloc ... {
  final Repo _repo;
}

class EditDialogBloc ... {
  final Repo _repo;
}
```

The repository object is created in *list view widget* then passed to `ListViewBloc`.

On listview selection (tap) I need to open the *detail view widget* (actually new route) which is managed by the `EditDialogBloc`.

How can I pass the already create instance of repository to detail route in web **using `go_router`**?

I.e. I have a route `/#customers` which creates a `Repo` then route switches to `/#customers/1` which should use the same `Repo`. Also it should be taken into account that user may clicks F5 (refresh) and `Repo` instance must be available

Comment: What do you mean by "repository"?

Answer (score 1):

There is not a single solution to you proble, it will depend on what architecture you want to have in your app. You have two options:

## Options 1: Passing an "extra" object to your route

You could use the `extra` parameter:

```dart
context.go('destination-route', extra: repo);
```

Then in your router definition you will take that parameter from the [GoRouterState](https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/go_router/GoRouterState-class.html):

```dart
GoRoute(
    path: 'destination-route',
    name: 'destination-route-name',
    builder: (context, state) {
            return DestinationPageWidget(
                repo: state.extra,
            );
        },
    )
```

**NOTE**: The `extra` field of the GoRouterState state can be null.

**WARNING**: You should NOT use the extra parameter if you are planning to have a Flutter Web app, since it is not ensure to be present.

## Option 2: Using a state-management technique

As indicated above, you should NOT use the extra parameter if you are planning to have a Flutter Web app. In that case **you cannot use GoRouter** and should use another approach such as any [state-management techniques](https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options) that are independent from your widgets and BuildContext, such as GetIt or Redux, or you could make your Repo class a [singleton](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/singleton).

```dart
class Repo {
  // Singleton instance.
  static final Repo instance = Repo._();

  // Default private constructor.
  Repo._();

  // Your methods...
}
```

```dart
class ListViewBloc ... {
  final Repo _repo = Repo.instance;
}
class EditDialogBloc ... {
  final Repo _repo = Repo.instance;
}
```

Comment: Actually I have a web app. I used `go` with second parameter before but this works until user clicks F5 (I meantioned this in a question). After refresh the `state.extra` is null and off course I cannot pass repository object via parameter.

Comment: I have updated my answer based on the updates on your question

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 most common package to reuse existing `Repositories`/`Services`/`Data Sources` depening on the choosen naming.

- [GetIt](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) - Global instance accessor
- [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) - Inherited Widget wrapper

For the usage i advice reading documentation.

Assuming that your `Repositories`/`Services`/`Data Sources` are not persisting any `State` you could also create a new instance and pass it into chosen `State` - `bloc` in your case.

Comment: The question was **How to pass... ?** So please show me the short example how do you pass the object (in my case repository) from one route to another.

Comment: @BambinoUA your question is not clear. Using Provider or GetIt as suggested could be a possible solution to your question. Please be more specific.

Comment: @pcba-dev I've updated the question. And yes I know for what `Provider` is used. The question how to pass (provide) the object using `go_router`'.